# What is the reason behind my application service suddenly stopped?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-services

The server Service is “Mss.exe” which is running under account “stepup” account which I checked from “services.msc”  and system configuration is 2003 server 32bit standard edition with SP2.  But yesterday means November 20 it suddenly stopped , I don’t know what is the reason behind it.

The entries in **event log**  are

Following error also i can see somewhere

```
Event ID ( 8500 ) in Source ( LeafTest)
cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry
information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer.
```

When I go0gled somewhere its mentioning my application may not be installed properly or registered or I need to work with registry. Can any body tell me what will be the reason behind the service stpped by reading logs which i have posted

Comment: I don't know the reasons... But maybe something that could help you is check your service enviroment. I mean, is your Windows updated with all patches installed? Does the disk is OK, without crashes, badblocks and defragmented? Maybe the problem would not be the service by itself but the enviroment envolved.

Comment: Please don't cross-post between StackExchange Sites (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244853/what-would-be-the-reason-behind-the-window-service-stop)

Comment: @Steve - I don't know Steve, I never had this specific problem before. Did I tried to look on google?

Comment: Please don't crosspost. [What would be the reason behind the window service stop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8244853)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Event Id error is just telling you that the service wasn't properly registered with the event log system (needs to be done intentionally by the software/service), so there's no further event log info (description) registered for the Event ID thrown by the program (19025).

0xc0000005 is an Access Violation and are usually caused by memory corruption.  Could be anything from bad RAM, to the software trying to access a non-existing array index.

Some things to try:

Test your RAM, try the service on another machine, if you have access to the code then perhaps attach a debugger to it.

Comment: That's a red herring (it's not your problem), it's just telling you it can't give you better Event Id log information because the program was not written to provide it, or it didn't register/provide a description for that specific Event Id.   19025 could mean whatever the author of the software decided it means.  Unless you wrote it, or have the code to figure out the Event Id and or what's happening, then you should just start testing/swapping RAM.

Comment: This is a lot of questions for this one question. ;)  I'd advise doing some googling and posting new, specific questions.  The Group Policy event is simply telling you Group policy has been applied, which happens at boot and every hour (usually).  the other is telling you that the process failed and restarted 4 times, which has exceeded some threshold.